# AJAX JQuery form submit only works once( requires page refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

When the page loads I can retrieve one result, but when I change the inputs and try to repopulate the update_form I receive nothing. Any ideas? When I check the parameters the browser is receiving the new parameters, but apparently the query is not be run again.

```
$(function() { 
                $("#select_form").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'select_price.php',
                        data: $('#select_form').serialize(),
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);

                            if(data){
                                $("#update_form").html(data);
                                $("#norecord").css('display','none');

                            }
                           else{
                                $("#norecord").css('display','block');

                            }

                        },


                    });

                });
                });
```

My HTML

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="select_form"><select style="max-width: 125px;border-radius:5px;" class="form-control" name="cus_no" autocomplete="off">
                <?php

                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT debcode FROM cicmpy WHERE cicmpy.region IS NOT NULL";
                $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
                while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . ($row['debcode']) . '">' .($row['debcode']) . ' </option>';
                }


                ?>

                </select ></div><label>Item Number</label><input style="max-width: 125px; border-radius:5px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="auto_item" name="item_no"/>
                        <button style="margin-top: 15px;" type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</button>
                        <button style="margin-top: 15px;" type="button" name="new_price" id="new_price" class="btn btn-success pull-right">New Price</button></div>
        </div> </div>
                   </div>
        </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your HTML (the whole form)?

Comment: @pmahomme Strange it wasn't showing up. fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your HTML, give your button an `id="btn_manage"` and remove the `type="submit"`, otherwise you're just POSTing the form (which is why your page is refreshing) instead of using AJAX. In your Javascript, get rid of the `$("#select_form").submit(function (e) {` stuff and simply register an event handler for the button itself, which will run the AJAX.

Update the HTML and then try this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#btn_manage").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'select_price.php',
                data: $('#select_form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    if(data){
                        $("#update_form").html(data);
                        $("#norecord").css('display','none');

                    } else {
                        $("#norecord").css('display','block');

                    }

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Error: " + data)
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: This worked great. This also fixed my two buttons on one form issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a click event handler for the submit button that will be added in the future ajax requests this way.

```
$(function() {
  $("#select_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'select_price.php',
      data: $('#select_form').serialize(),
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        if (data) {
          $("#update_form").html(data);
          $("#norecord").css('display', 'none');

        } else {
          $("#norecord").css('display', 'block');

        }

      },


    });

  });

    //Bind click event listener to the submit button
    $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function() {
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you go more into detail? Is this exactly how it would look?